# Worst and best case time complexity

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I need help understanding the worst and best case time complexity for the following code example. How can I represent the time as a function T(n) if each line of code takes X time?

Thank you.

```
SORT(X)

    for i = 0 to X.length - 1
        
        for j = X.length downto i + 1
            
            if X[j] < X[j-1]
            
                change X[j] with X[j-1]
```

Comment: The best case occurs when the last line is never executed (this is possible).

Comment: I need to represent the answer as  T(n) =

Comment: What is holding you back from doing that ?

Comment: I have just started learning about all this and am not good at it; I want to understand and ensure that I'm doing the right thing.

Comment: Well, show us what you tried (this is how this site works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, best case occurs when for all `j`, `X[j] >= X[j - 1]`, that is, your list `X` is already sorted in ascending order. Worst case occurs when for all `j`, `X[j] < X[j - 1]`, that is, your list `X` is already sorted in descending order. However notice that regardless of the situation, we have to iterate through the loops and execute the if statement. Only difference is the swapping operations, which won't effect the time complexity analysis.

For all `i`, we iterate from `X.length` to `i+1`. 
For `i` = 0, iterate from `X.length` downto `1`: `n` operations (assuming `X` has `n` elements.) 
For `i` = 1, iterate from `X.length` downto `2`: `n-1` operations 
For `i` = 2, iterate from `X.length` downto `2`: `n-2` operations 
... 
For `i` = `X.length` - 1, iterate from `X.length` downto `X.length`: `1` operations 
Sum the number of operations:  `n` + `n-1` + ... + `1` = (`n+1`) . (`n`) / 2

Therefore we can conclude that `T(n) = n*(n+1)/2`. Time complexity for both of the cases (worst-best) becomes: `O(n^2)`.

Comment: The best case is easy to prove, as no swaps are performed. The worst case is more subtle because the initial order is perturbed... (Of course, that does not modify the asymptotic expression.)

Comment: @Muhteva, thanks for the great explanation. So if I understand correctly: The first line will be n(n+1) and the second line will be n*n(n+1)? what about the IF statement and the last change line? and why did you use (n)/2 ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust is right. Worst case will change the ```T(n)``` a little bit. However it won't affect the big-Oh analysis. It will still have quadratic time complexity.

Comment: @ThreeTherteen consider first line as the incrementation operation. We will increment ```i```  ```n``` times. And we will perform the comparison operation ```n*(n+1)/2``` times as explained above. In worst case, you should also include swap operation. If swap is not atomic (idk if it's correct word to use here), then it will introduce 3 basic operations. It will be something like ```T(n) = n*(n+1)/2 * 4```. Therefore ```O(n^2)``` won't change.

Comment: What is the time for the IF statement? and if execute the change statement? also, why did we divide by 2?

Comment: What do you mean by the "Time for the IF statement"? We divide by 2 because we added numbers from 1 to ```n```. It's a simple formula, you can google it by writing "sum of numbers from 1 to ```n```".

Comment: I mean what is the time for executing the IF statement, for example 1 or n,

Comment: So, worst case will be T(n) = n*(n+1)/2. and best case is T(n) = n*(n+1)/2 * 4 which will equal to O(n^2)

Comment: I assume the time it takes to execute the IF statement to be unit (1). In best case, IF statement is executed ```n*(n+1)/2``` times. In worst case, still it is executed ```n*(n+1)/2``` times. However, in worst case, swap operation is also executed ```n*(n+1)/2``` times. In my comment above, I've divided swap into three basic operations and concluded that ```T(n) = n*(n+1)/2 * 4```. However, dividing the swapping into three basic operations was my wild guess, so be careful about that.

Comment: Is there a way to chat with you about this?

Comment: There is a chat option to continue further the discussion, however unfortunately you don't have enough reputation to join a chat channel, and I don't really know the basics since I haven't used it for a while. I can try to help if you want to ask further questions about the problem from here.

Comment: Why are we using the summing formula? the function is to sort array X. do you have facebook?

Comment: We summed the number of basic operations performed for the inner loop for each ```i``` value. It's not related to the algorithm.

Comment: @Muhteva, what does "downto" in the for loop mean? can you write the same pseudo-code example in actual code? I'm confused because of this pseudo-code.

Comment: ```for(int j = X.length(); j>= i+1; j--)```. It may change from language to language. But it sohuld be clear enough.

Comment: @Muhteva, Thank you so much. It is much clearer now. Can you do the first line also?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, first line is just the name of the function, it doesn't contribute to the time complexity.